# Transform Array[Seq[(Int, String)]] to Seq[(Int, String)] in SCALA

Tags: scala

I'm pretty new to scala and I can't find a way to get rid of my Array[Seq[(Int, String)]] to one big Seq[(Int, String)] containing the (Int, String) of each Seq[(Int, String)].

Here is a more explicit example:

### Array[Seq[(Int, String)]]:

ArrayBuffer((1,a), (1,group), (1,of))

ArrayBuffer((2,following), (2,clues))

ArrayBuffer((3,three), (3,girls))

### And here is what I want my Seq[(Int, String)]] to looks like:

Seq((1,a), (1,group), (1,of), (2,following), (2,clues), (3,three), (3,girls))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [flatten](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala_collections/scala_collections_flatten.htm): `val flat: Array[(Int, String)] = originalArray.flatten`

If you want it to be a `Seq` rather than an array (good choice), just tuck a `.toSeq` at the end: `originalArray.flatten.toSeq`